# Rewrites and redirects in AWS amplify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-router, aws-amplify

I am new to `AWS deployment` and trying to deploy both Backends (`NodeJS, Express, MongoDB`) and Frontend(`React/Redux`) code to AWS. I am using `AWS Beanstalk` for backend and `AWS amplify` for Frontend code. I have completed the backend deployment and tested it using postman and even testing the API's by running frontend at `http://localhost:3000/`. I have deployed the code on AWS amplify also but seems I am not aware of the `Rewrites and redirects` it uses so that the app can navigate to different URL's. Mine is a `SPA`. I can see the login screen but once I enter the credentials it dosen't navigate to protected(Using `JWT Auth`) URL.

My app on amplify is hosted on : `https://url-resolve-changes.d1z993fyobkz3s.amplifyapp.com/`

App.js -> Contains different routes. Apart from `/login` and `/register` all the routes have to be checked first using PrivateRoute and then can render the Homepage. I declared BASE_URL = host but I am not sure how I can use it that to navigate on different URL's

```
// const BASE_URL = "https://url-resolve-changes.d1z993fyobkz3s.amplifyapp.com";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MessageSnackbar />
        <Router history={history}>
          <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path={`/`}
              renderFunc={routeProps => <HomePage {...routeProps} />}
            />
            <Route path={`/login`} component={Login} />
            <Route path={`/register`} component={Register} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withTheme()(App);
```

I have below configured in Rewrites and redirects in the Amplify settings.

[image]

manifest.json

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

The issue is that nothing loads as of now when I hit :

```
https://url-resolve-changes.d1z993fyobkz3s.amplifyapp.com/index.html
```

OR

```
https://url-resolve-changes.d1z993fyobkz3s.amplifyapp.com/
```

The backend URL though is correctly configured as when I send the request from `http://localhost:3000/` the API's are working fine. It's just the redirecting part I am missing. Do let me know if any other details are required.
Appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I had a problem when **refreshing page with route path,
received response AccessDenied**, caused by S3 does not really have that path or file. Got this question first on search result, so posting my solution here.

**Resolved the issue** by:

Original address:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

[image: configured in Rewrites and redirects in the Amplify settings:]

[Redirects for single page web apps (SPA)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa)

> Most SPA frameworks support HTML5 history.pushState() to change browser location without triggering a server request. This works for users who begin their journey from the root (or /index.html), but fails for users who navigate directly to any other page. Using regular expressions, the following example sets up a 200 rewrite for all files to index.html except for the specific file extensions specified in the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

While I reshared your question on https://twitter.com/nswebstudio/status/1149276084304613376 
I figured it out its amplify.yml issue. I corrected my Build path as follows

```
baseDirectory: build
```

Complete amplify.yml file screenshot 
[image]

Also read for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/build-settings.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Answer

You need to specify that only html files get rewritten using:

```
/<*>.html
```

As your Source Address.

## Answer for more control

The answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431987/9041460) posted by [@mvladk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578264/mvladk) correctly shows the version which adds more control if you want other files to get rewritten and control the ones that don't instead using:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

as your source address, as mentioned by AWS in:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Just a question of if you want to have an include list of files to rewrite or an exclude list. Just hit this stumbling block for a sec too and though I should contribute.