React app deploying into subdirectory, nested page not working
I am deploying a simple app with create-react-app to a subdirectory.
I have set the homepage from package.json as below:
"homepage": "/subdir/",


and here's the simplified code I'm using:
function App() {

  return (
  
    <BrowserRouter basename={"/subdir"}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"/"} element={<Landing />} />
        <Route path={"/test"} element={<h1>TEST</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;

This works with no problem in localhost dev mode. (npm start)
However, when built and deployed, the nested page, url.com/subdir/test returns 404. (url.com/subdir works fine.)
also when the app is built (npm run build) and tested in local web server, same problem occurs.
I am deploying it to AWS Amplify and all rewrites and redirects are turned off.
I have tried using HashRouter, also tried nesting the routes.
I have also tried not using basename.
Still nothing seems to work.
Would anyone know how to fix this? thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431987/1086398 will sort this out. The problem is the web server needs to be configured such that all paths serve the core index.html. For you the source address field will be /subdir/</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/> and the target address will be /subdir/index.html.
